# Capturing SHIFT + TAB and TAB only button presses in Win32 App

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have  a Win32 App on which i want to capture the SHIFT + TAB button press on keyboard and TAB only keyboard button press. I want to capture both these in the **PreTranslateMessage** fucntion.

This will enable me to do some custom operations based on these keyboard presses.

Right now the code i have is,

```
if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && pMsg->wParam == VK_SHIFT)
    {
        m_shiftKey = TRUE;
    }

    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && pMsg->wParam == VK_TAB)
    {
        // DO Something
        m_shiftKey = FALSE;
        return TRUE;
    }

    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && m_shiftKey && pMsg->wParam == VK_TAB) 
    {
        // DO Something
        return TRUE;
    }
```

I can get the TAB key press fine here, but the combination of SHIFT + TAB doesn't work properly here.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system does not generate keyboard input messages for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. You can, however, query for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key's current state calling [GetKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx).

One solution to your problem is to replace your first `if` clause with the following code:

```
m_shiftKey = ( ::GetKeyState( VK_SHIFT ) < 0 ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

A word of warning: Code in `PreTranslateMessage` is only executed, if the application hasn't entered a modal loop. A modal loop is entered whenever a modal dialog is opened, a window is moved or resized, or a menu is opened.